# jqGrid multi-select sort/show checked items at the top always

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a a jqGrid that shows as list of rows ... several thousand.

When the grid loads, it will pull down all the data with their previous selections already checked.

My questions is, **how do I set the sort order to always show the selected items at the top?**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You question seems be very close to another one which I answered recently (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123825/bring-selected-rows-to-the-top-from-the-jqgrid/8138980#8138980)). If you has several thousand or event thousand rows you *should* use paging of date to improve performance of the grid. The solution which I suggested is very simple and it supports saving of selected state over the paging.

One more remark. If you have jqGrid with local data you can implement *custom sorting of data*. To do this you just need define `sorttype` **as function**. If the data need be sorted by a column jqGrid will compare items. The function `sorttype` should just return any string or number which should be used *instead of the cell value*. In the case you can easy place for example selected items at the top of grid. You can find examples of custom formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917321/jqgrid-custom-sorting/8001822#8001822), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324613/jqgrid-with-custom-sorttype/3329852#3329852) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/searching-on-text-field-with-accentued-chars-on-local-datas/#p22085).

Comment: This truly answers my question, however, I want to keep the select all feature.

Comment: @Adam: If you read my previous answer you will understand that you need just comment in the demo lines starting with `$("#cb_" + $grid[0].id).hide();`. Then you will have select all feature. You should implement custom sorting of data `sorttype` as function to hold the selected items on top.

Comment: I did notice that in the example, however it does not let the select all function work. When I click the checkbox, it sorts the column instead of selecting all.