# I need to expand all sub groups when main group is clicked

Tags: jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2 jqgrid i want to know if there is a method which i can use to expand all sub groups when main group is clicked in grid. For example

```
-grp1
 +subgrp1
 +subgrp2
-grp2
 +subgrp1
 +subgrp2
+grp3
```

so when i click on `+` sign on grp3 the subgrp will also be expanded. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandingStateOfGroups.htm) created for [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369526/315935) and [the modified one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandingStateOfGroups_.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317759/315935). It uses [groupingToggle](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping&s[]=groupingtoggle#methods) method to expand the group by API. What you need is just another enumeration of subgroups, but it seems that one can use almost the same code to solve your problem.