# jqgrid group expand/collapse event

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, expand

Is there an event that is fired from jqGrid to notify that a certain group is expanded or collapsed?
I have searched in the internet and I found there is an event for treeGrid but not sure about jqGrid.
I wonder if jqGrid has one so we can know if user is expanding / collapsing certain group by listening to that event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exist callback `onClickGroup` starting with jqGrid 4.0.0 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#jqgrid_4.0.0_changes_and_fixes)) and jQuery Event `jqGridGroupingClickGroup` starting with [4.3.2](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2). The parameters are `hid`, `collapsed`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317759/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369526/315935) for the corresponding code examples.

Comment: Is an event handler triggered when a group header row is clicked?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Not exactly. It will be called at the end of `groupingToggle` method. The method can be called by API or on click on the "+"/"-" expand/collapse button in the grouping header. There are currently no callback which will be called on click on the other part of  group header row or group summary row. You can just define `click` handler on the whole `<table>` (grid) and analyse `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgroup")`. It it's empty then one clicked not on the grouping header row. You can ask separate question if you would have implementation problems.