# looking at the nth page of a dataSet when using jqGrid onDocument.Ready

Tags: jqgrid, jquery, double-click

I have a sort of unique question that I can't seem to find an answer to.

I have a paged jqGrid implemented.  When I double click on a row on any page of data, my plan was to use the onDoubleClick event and have a function with an (id) parameter to take the id of the row, and pass it down to an action method that I have that will then redirect my page to an edit page (I don't use the jqGrid edit popup... That would be too many modal windows on my site). My problem is that once I edit that patient, I want to redirect back to the SAME page (of data) that I clicked away from to get to this edit page.  And when I say same page, I will be redirecting to the same grid, I want to get back to the same page of data that held the row that I just clicked on.  To me, the easiest way to do this would be to send the page and row information down to the action method that I use to call the edit page.

I can redirect back to the first page of data... But I want the user to see the change that he made to that person.  And that could be on the nth page of the data...

I thought I came up with a solution for this...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var pageFromTemp = '@TempData["PAGEVAR"]';
        var rowFromTemp = '@TempData["ROWVAR"]';
        var pId = '@TempData["POPULATIONID"]';
        if ((rowFromTemp != "") && (pageFromTemp != "")) {
            //loadPage(pageFromTemp, rowFromTemp, pId);
            $("#ftTable").setGridParam({ page: pageFromTemp });
            $("ftTable").setGridParam({ rowNum: rowFromTemp });
        }
        //else {
        jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid({
```

as you can see, on $(document).ready(function (){} I get page information that I have saved to redirect to this page, and I attempt to set it with the setGridParam function.  Unfortunately, I still redirect back to the first page of data.  Is there a way that I can set jqGrid to open up to an Nth page of the data?

Answer (score 1):

The following will reload the grid and set it to a particular page.  You will have to take care around the filtering, sorting, etc that was present during the first view of the grid where the double click occurred and depending on your use case possibly pass that up during the reload of the grid.

```
$(gridName).jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: X}]);
```

Comment: When I attempt to do this, my jqGrid, simply doesn't load.  Should I have the the id of the grid inside here... jqGrid("#id")?  I guess a question I would have is, how would I initialize a grid on page N?

Comment: This should work, I just tested and replacing the "gridName" and "X" should work.  You can test in firebug as well.

Comment: I don't know what it is... Whenever I do this, the grid just doesn't load...  I have tried it in chrome, ff, IE.  I am trying to find a way to initialize jqGrid to page n.  I am thinking if the grid wasn't even loaded, how can it 'reload' to page n?

Comment: When the reload goes out it will pass to the controller what page you are requesting, you should see the page value it go out in your POST.

Comment: I can see the page value in the Url string of the site... But as I live and breath the grid doesn't even load.  I am thinking the grid is even initialized with any of the options it needs, so reloading it is pointless.  I am thinking that I have to set the page during some kind of pre-init event... That is where I am focusing my attention at the moment.  One thing I may not have mentioned, when I save I hit an action, and then re-route the beginning... It's not like I am just hitting the back button.

Comment: ok... I got the grid to load, but now it isn't returning any paged data at all... Looks like it might have had an exception somewhere.

Comment: Firebug or it's other browser equivalent is your friend :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25380/discussion-between-dmainevent-and-mark)

Comment: @DmainEvent Did this end up working for you? Please mark as correct if so.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to save the state of the grid is the usage of `localStorage`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) and [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935).

Just try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm). You can choose 5 rows per page, choose the second page in the grid, select some row. Then go to any other page and open the demo one more time. You can just reload the page using <kbd>F5</kbd> key. You will see that the previously selected page and the previously selected row will be restored. So all works like you want to implement. Additionally it will be saved many other parameters which are the state of the grid. It improves the user's experience and makes working with the grid more comfortable.