# how to get focus on previous selected row with page in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am try to get focus on jqgrid previous selected row with page but I could't do it.so please give a solution for that.

Comment: You should describe the problem more clear. First jqGrid don't set focus on rows. Do you use `bindKeys` method or you used just wrong terminology and you mean only selection of rows? What scenario you mean? *When* the row should be selected? What you mean under *"previous selected row"*? Do you mean that the user visit the same page twice and you want that the row selection from the first visit will be displayed at the second visit?

Comment: exactly what I want,once user login in application  ,there are some  links to another pages,when user come to home page user want selected row when he was selected on home page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the id of selected row for example in `localStorage` of web browsers. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) or [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_.htm) which uses `multiselect: true` option. The demos do what you asked. Both demos are from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) which is modification of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) which I posed before and where I discuss advantages of usage `localStorage` instead of cookie.