# jqGrid - Keep vertical scroll bar visible with both horizontal and vertical scrollbars

Tags: css, jqgrid, scroll

The situation is a jqGrid inside a div where the size of the grid is larger than the div both vertically and horizontally. The goal is to have the column headers scroll left and right with horizontal scroll, and also keep them always visible when scrolling vertically.

It is easy enough to add CSS to have both scrollbars by setting overflow-x: auto to the div containing the jqGrid and overflow-y to auto for the ui-jqgrid-bdiv.

The problem with this technique is that the vertical scrollbar is only visible when the grid is scrolled horizontally to the right enough to show the right side of the grid. Making the ui-jqgrid-bdiv scroll and using DOM manipulation to set the sizes of the containing elements results in both scrollbars being visible, but the body content scrolls without scrolling the column headers.

There is a similar stack overflow question [JqGrid add vertical scroll with horizontal scolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603830/jqgrid-add-vertical-scroll-with-horizontal-scolling), but the answers do not address this.

It doesn't look as if there would be a pure CSS solution given the DOM structure of the grid. Is there a JavaScript solution out there, perhaps one listening to scroll events?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `height` and `width` property of the grid itself so that the grid will take care of the scrolling instead of the `div` that it is nested in. Set the dimensions to be the same or slightly smaller than the `div`'s.

```
<div style="height:200px; width:100px;">
    <table id="grid"></table>
</div>

<script>
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    height: '200',
    width: '100',
    shrinkToFit: false //Tells the grid to let columns go to set size
    //Add all your properties
});
</script>
```

**OR**

if you can get away with not setting the `width` and `height` of the parent `div`, you can just set the grid's dimensions like shown above. As long as the grid's properties are set to a certain size, it will make it's own scroll bars if the data is outside of those bounds.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/8017/)