# How to keep dropdown selected with one value in filter dropdown in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have scenario where I am using one jqgrid with dropdowns and tetxtboxes as filter like  [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching)

lets assume one dropdown is having values - All, First, Second, Third, Fourth.

1) I select "First" and rows gets filtered with that value.

2) I edit that row, control navigate to other page, I save the data and come back to previous page.

3) This time I am not seeing my dropdown with value "First" as prepopulated. Its showing me "All" and I am seeing ALL data not the filtered one.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you use **different** web pages and you want that the page with jqGrid and the filter toolbar **persist** the last choice in the filter toolbar. One of the possible implementation of such scenario is described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935). Just try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) from the second answer, set some filter and *reload* the page with F5. You will see that the page persist the last choice of filtering. The implementation is not very simple, but it seems to me that it is what you need.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Even on my page refresh filter dropdowns are getting reset. I saw other posts too and noticed that you answered number of them. And honestly speaking, I was waiting for you. Let me try with the solutions that you are suggesting here. Thanks

Comment: @Jaikrat: You are welcome! I can repeat that the implementation of persistent grid is not simple, but it's really practical for users.