# change page on delete using multiselect in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to know how to delete rows if I have 11 records and my rown Num is 10 in Multiselect jqgrid.

I want to select rows in page1 and select 11th row in page 2 and when i click on delete the rows which I selected in page1 is also to be deleted along with selected row in page2.

is it possible?
Can anyone share code or demo of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select rows on the page which is not visible (page 2). If it's really required you will need to hold the ids of selected rows manually and set `selarrrow` inside of `loadComplete` with respect of `setSelection`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172723/315935) for more information and for the demo example.

Comment: By seeing this demo I have done the selection in other pages,but my problem is If i try to delete,I am able to delete which is visibile and I am not able to delete row which is not visible.

Comment: @user1268130: I answered you in your previous question that you need to change `data` (and probably `_index` depend from scenario) *manually*. jqGrid has no methods to manipulate the *whole* local data of the grid over the pages. So one have to do this manually. After you changed `data` you can trigger `reloadGrid` to have grid corresponds to new `data`.

Comment: My Colleague has solved this issue by using backbone.js where I dont have idea how he solved it as I dont have idea on Backbone