# JqGrid set select a row with a particular data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a requirement to set select a row when the grid is loading ,based on the data value of a column in a particular row. ( In my case select the row with invoice number IVAXVL18066996 / refer the attachment ).

[image]

I am researching solution for awhile and still can not find favorable answer. I ll really appreciate if someone can help here with this matter

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the answer from here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095433/select-a-row-in-jqgrid-based-on-cell-value

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestions of @Madalinul and @Mark I sorted the problem. The fix is as follows

```
loadComplete : function(data) {
  var rowIds = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

  for (i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {
    var invNumberFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getCell', rowIds[i], 'invoiceNumber');

    if (invNumberFromGrid === generatedInvoiceNumber) {
      grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowIds[i], true);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

All credit goes to them and the community. Many thanks