# jqgrid: multiselect checkbox values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I add `multiselect: true` to my jqgrid, I see that jqgrid adds a checkbox for each row.  Each checkbox that is displayed is unchecked.  Is there a way I can preset these checkboxes based on data I'm using to populate my grid?  For example, if my grid has a column called **selected**, and a row I'm displaying has a selected value of **1**, I'd like to display the checkbox for that row as being checked.  When a row's selected field is **0**, I'd like to keep the checkbox as unchecked.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on your question depends on the fork of jqGrid, which you use. I develop free jqGrid fork and implemented `multiPageSelection: true` option. One need just fill `selarrrow` array (which you can do, for example, inside of `beforeProcessing` based on the data returned from the server). Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935). It shows that the `selarrrow` array contains the ids more as on the current page. On paging or during initial filling free jqGrid *set the state of chechboxes* based on the `selarrrow` array. In the way it works effective like custom formatters, `rowattr` or `cellattr`.

If you can't upgrade to free jqGrid then you can call `setSelection` inside of `loadComplete` (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172723/315935)). It will work slower as in case of usage `multiPageSelection: true`, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In `loadComplete`, have something like this

```
var i;
var rowids = $('#myTable').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (i = 0;i < count = rowids.length;i+=1) {
    // condition to mark it check
    $('#myTable').jqGrid('setSelection', rowids[i], false);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the data and apply the check.

Comment: I'm curious on how I would do that, given that the "cb" column that jqgrid adds on the fly is not part of the column model I'm defining.

Comment: Yes you will need to do this after the column are generated.  based in index id which is generated for all the checkbox

Comment: How do I know when the columns are generated?

Comment: Once the page is redered. Or better write a custom function using formatter options to apply the change.