# Prevent reset selection jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How prevent reset the selection rows on jqgrid to change of page
jqgrid  code:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'data.json',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [         
        { label: 'ID', name: 'ProductID', width: 45, key: true },
        { label: 'Category Name', name: 'CategoryName', width: 75 },
        { label: 'Product Name', name: 'ProductName', width: 90 },
        { label: 'Country', name: 'Country', width: 100 },
        { label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 80, sorttype: 'integer' },
        // sorttype is used only if the data is loaded locally or loadonce is set to true
        { label: 'Quantity', name: 'Quantity', width: 80, sorttype: 'number' }                   
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 780,
    height: 200,
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList : [20,30,50],
    rownumbers: true, 
    rownumWidth: 25, 
    multiselect: true,
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
});
```

why reset selection rows in jqgrid when i change to another page..
example:
I select first row, change to next page and select first row from the second page and i try get the selected rows and only return the last..dont the all selected rows...

please maybe any suggest to fix this problem..thanks..!!
note..the same error on the official example of seleccion ->CheckBox selection

[official example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)

Comment: The solution of your problem is heavy depend on the **version** the the **fork** of jqGrid, which you use. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, has the feature. You need just add the option `multiPageSelection: true` additionally to `multiselect: true`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm), which I created for **Updated** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172723/315935). [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172723/315935) describes alternative solution, which works for old jqGrid.

Comment: This feature in Guriddo jqGid will be available in the upcoming release at end of this month

Comment: @Tony Tomov my jqGid  load data from server and I'm using v 5.3.2. But its still not working. When I change to local data then its working just fine. Whats the problem so far??

Comment: @Atanu Did you have read what are the needed settings to do this? Please provide a example demonstrating the problem!