# Post Data Getting Lost during Ajax Post Request in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, request

I am working on an ASP.net MVC 3.0 Application with razor view engine.

I am making an ajax post as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "post",                                                                  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       url: GetErrorCountUrl,
         success: function (data) {
           });
```

Here, the URL is as follows:

```
var GetErrorCountUrl = '@Url.Action("GetErrorCount", "WError", new { Id= "Token", id1 = "Token1", id2= "Token2" })';
GetErrorCountUrl = GetErrorCountUrl.replace('Token',pkid).replace('Token1',cid).replace('Token2',itemclass);
```

I am building the correct URL . I checked by using alert(url). It is hitting that controller action.

In my controller action,

If i do :   Request.params["Id"] --> I was getting the correct value

```
         Reuqest.params["id1"] --> I am getting null values
```

but, when i do:

```
       reuqest.Params[0] --> correct value

       request.params[1]  ---> Correct value
```

I was getting correct values when using index instead of name.

I need get those values based on Parameter name not on index.

Please help.

**Except for the first parameter..i was not able to get the values of other parameters**

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name of variabeles should start with low letter in JavaScript. Names with the first capital variable should be used only for classes (functions used in constructors). Prettify formatting of the code used on stackoverflow uses other colors for JavaScript classes. For example to define data in JavaScript one should use `var d = new Date();` instead of `var d = new Date();`. So the code like `var GetErrorCountUrl = "some string";` looks in JavaScript very strange. I understand that JavaScript is not your main language, but it's really better the name conversion used in the language which one uses.

Now back to your main question. It seems to me that

```
GetErrorCountUrl.replace('Token',pkid).replace('Token1',cid).replace('Token2',itemclass);
```

Isn't what you really want. If the string `GetErrorCountUrl` contains `'Token1'` then the `'Token'` part of the substring `'Token1'` will be first replaced to `pkid` and the next replacement (to `cid`) will never work.

To fix the problem you can change the order or replacements to the following for example:

```
GetErrorCountUrl.replace('Token1',cid)
    .replace('Token2',itemclass)
    .replace('Token',pkid);
```

Comment: @Oleg..Thanks for your sugesstions. I will definitely look into my naming conventions. But, still after re arranging , i was getting null values

Comment: @Oleg..The Url is building correctly..i checked it by using alert(url). The Problem is recieving them on Controller action. When i check using indexes, they are working. If i am trying to fecth using parameter names, i am getting null values.

Comment: @Avinash: Probably you removed the real problem which you have by writing the text of the question. For example the statement `var GetErrorCountUrl = '@Url.Action("GetErrorCount", "WError", new { Id= "Token", id1 = "Token1", id2= "Token2" })';` works only once. If you opens the source of the generated page you will see `var GetErrorCountUrl = 'someString';` only. Could you includes **the final string** which assigned to the variable `GetErrorCountUrl`?

Comment: @Oleg..Sorry oleg..i am not understanding where to check..Is there any other way of passing parmateters to Controller.using jquery ajax post

Comment: @Oleg..After all replaces, i was getting URL some thing like:

Comment: @Avinash: `@Url.Action` is just macro which will be replaces by razor *on the server*. The client (web browser) see only the results of the substitution. You just opens you page on which you use the code `var GetErrorCountUrl = '@Url.Action("GetErrorCount", ...);`, then you use context menu of the web browser and chose "View Source" or "View Page Source". Then you search for the text "var GetErrorCountUrl = " and see it's value.

Comment: .@Oleg..After all replaces, i was getting URL some thing like: /Error/GetErrorCount/paramtervalues

Comment: @Avinash: Sorry, but where in the URL are `Token`, `Token1` or `Token` now? Which form contains `paramtervalues` (for example `?param1=value1&param2=value2` or `/value1/value2` or some other?). Could you post **full** code fragment of JavaScript code which are on the client side? In the case one could see what JavaScript code exactly will be executed. It you have problem with calling of the action `GetErrorCount` then it would be helpful to include the prototype (declaration) of `GetErrorCount` method and probably the routing rule if you added some custom rule.

Comment: @Oleg..i have another big error..can you please help me on this..i have not updated above question because i am getting lot of errors and need to solve on priority http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418738/difficulty-with-application-error-event-of-global-asax-in-asp-net-mvc-3-0-applic